# arduino low i2c read speed;

Tags: c++, performance, arduino, i2c

I'm currently working on a project using the genuino 101 where i need to read large amounts of data trough i2c, to fill an arbitrarily sized buffer.from the following image i can see that the read requests themselves only take about 3 milliseconds and the write request about 200 nanoseconds.

[image: Read Transactions]

however there is a very large time (750+ ms) between read transactions in the same block

```
#define RD_BUF_SIZE 32
void i2cRead(unsigned char device, unsigned char memory, int len, unsigned char * rdBuf)
{
     ushort bytesRead = 0;
     ushort _memstart = memory;
     while (bytesRead < len) 
     {
         Wire.beginTransmission((int)device);
         Wire.write(_memstart);
         Wire.endTransmission();
         Wire.requestFrom((int)device, BLCK_SIZE);
         int i = 0;
         while (Wire.available()) 
         {
              rdBuf[bytesRead+i] = Wire.read();
              i++;
         }
         bytesRead += BLCK_SIZE;
         _memstart += BLCK_SIZE;
     }
}
```

from my understanding this shouldn't take that long, unless adding to memstart and bytesRead is taking extremely long. by my, arguably limited, understanding of time complexity this function has a time complexity of O(n) and should, in the best case only take about 12 ms for a 128 byte query

Am i missing something?

Comment: You code seems a little skewed. The relation between `len` and `RD_BUF_SIZE` is not clear and may cause an overflow of the read buffer.

Comment: How many bytes are you requesting per call, i.e. what is the value of `len`?

Comment: In this case i'm requesting 128 bytes, I.e 4 blocks of 32. 
the naming could be a bit more clear, i'm actually allocating the value of length as size of the read buffer in the function that calls i2cRead, 

RD_BUF_SIZE, should probably be renamed to BLCK_SIZE to prevent confusion

Comment: `bytesRead += RD_BUF_SIZE;` does not match then, because you request and read 128 bytes, but increment the pointer by 32. You probably want to request the lesser number of `len` and the allocated buffer size.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, fixing that cut off about 100ms, bringing execution time to 600ms, which is still quite long

Comment: Notice that `Wire.write();` writes one *byte* only, so `ushort _memstart` may be an inappropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 700ms are not caused by the execution time of the few instructions in your function. Those should be done in microseconds. You may have a buffer overflow, or the other device might be delaying transfers, or there's another bug not related to buffer overflow.

This is about how I'd do it:

```
void i2cRead(unsigned char device, unsigned char memory, int len, unsigned char * rdBuf, int bufLen)
{
     ushort _memstart = memory;
     if ( bufLen < len ) {
         len = bufLen;
     }
     while (len > 0) 
     {
         Wire.beginTransmission((int)device);
         Wire.write(_memstart);
         Wire.endTransmission();

         int reqSize = 32;

         if ( len < reqSize ) {
             reqSize = len;
         }

         Wire.requestFrom((int)device, reqSize);

         while (Wire.available() && (len != 0)) 
         {
              *(rdBuf++) = Wire.read();
              _memstart++;
              len--;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, the reason i do while( bytesRead < len) is that users can (theoretically) input an arbitrarily large number, and it will still fill the read buffer up to the point that it can read.

Comment: Sure. But you *must* make sure never to read more bytes than the buffer can hold, no matter what the user thinks he wants.

Comment: i agree, in the user-facing function i get around this issue like so:

 unsigned char * rdBuf = new unsigned char[len];
 memset(rdBuf, 0, len);
 i2cRead(dev, mem, len, rdBuf);

Where dev. mem and len are sanitized user input

Comment: Ok, I guess you're fine then in that respect.

Comment: Maybe note that I adjust the number of bytes requested to match the length in case the latter is not a multiple of 32.

Comment: That's something i'll look into, 
i fixed the (possible) overflow issue with the following line,  (len - bytesRead > RD_BLCK_SIZE) ? blockSize = len - bytesRead : blockSize = RD_BLCK_SIZE ; replacing BLCK_SIZE with blockSize,